# Linear regression load model doesn't predict as expected

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, word-embeddings

I have trained a linear regression model, with sklearn, for a 5 star rating and it's good enough. I have used Doc2vec to create my vectors, and saved that model. Then I save the linear regression model to another file. What I'm trying to do is load the Doc2vec model and linear regression model and try to predict a new review.

There is something very strange about this prediction: whatever the input it always predicts around 2.1-3.0.

Thing is, I have a suggestion that it predicts around the average of 5 (which is 2.5 +/-) but this is not the case. I have printed when training the model the prediction value and the actual value of the test data and they range normally 1-5. So my idea is, that there is something wrong with the loading part of the code (or even the reshape of the new vector). This is my load code:

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from joblib import dump, load
import pickle
import re

model = Doc2Vec.load('../vectors/750000/doc2vec_model')

def cleanText(text):
    text = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").text
    text = re.sub(r'\|\|\|', r' ', text) 
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', r'<URL>', text)
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.replace('x', '')
    return text

review = cleanText("Horrible movie! I don't recommend it to anyone!").split()
vector = model.infer_vector(review)

pkl_filename = "../vectors/750000/linear_regression_model.joblib"
with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:  
    linreg = pickle.load(file)

review_vector = vector.reshape(1,-1)
predict_star = linreg.predict(review_vector)
print(predict_star)
```